# c program receiving ethernet frames - why specify the destination mac address

Tags: c, ethernet, mac-address

I am using these projects on github to send and receive ethernet frames over the two ethernet interfaces on my machine.

[Recieve ethernet](https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/2862515)

My question is in relation to the program for receiving the ethernet frames. Why do you have to supply the destination MAC in the receiving program? Should it not just be listening on the `eth0` interface?

```
#define DEST_MAC0   0x00
#define DEST_MAC1   0x00
#define DEST_MAC2   0x00
#define DEST_MAC3   0x00
#define DEST_MAC4   0x00
#define DEST_MAC5   0x00

#define ETHER_TYPE  0x0800

#define DEFAULT_IF  "eth0"
#define BUF_SIZ     1024
```

Comment: The program you link to sets the Ethernet interface to promiscuous mode. That means it will receive all packets on the interface, not just packets meant for the local host. Thus, they added a check for the destination MAC address.

Comment: Ok thanks, are you saying that destination MAC address in the program that receives the frames has to match the  destination MAC address specified in the program that sends the frames[link](https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/1922600)?